# how can I display thumbnail image in spite of bubble in google map API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, thumbnails

I am using google map api in my application. How can I show a thumbnail image in place of red bubble for a perticular address on Map.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the Marker, you set the icon.  i.e.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: null,
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(jdata.locationLat, jdata.locationLon),
  visible: true,
  clickable: true,
  title: jQuery.trim(jdata.locationName),
  icon: 'http://www.mysite.com/mythumb.png',
  shadow: 'http://www.mysite.com/markershadow.png'
});
```

You can set it after initialization as well:

```
marker.setIcon('http://www.mysite.com/mythumb.png');
marker.setShadow('http://www.mysite.com/markershadow.png');
```

Comment: I am using a user control where I am pointing address through javascript like-  map.setCenter(new GLatLng(latitude, longitude), parseFloat(document.getElementById(hdnZoom).value));

                           var point = new GLatLng(latlons[0], latlons[1]);
                           map.addOverlay(new GMarker(point));

Comment: You said you're using version 3 but those look like version 2 calls.  The option would go in the reference to creating a new marker.